# How to get only one row from excel which has multiple rows data?

Tags: java, excel

Actually, I have written code for reading data from an excel file.

But, I want to read the first row and if required then read the second row which is not happening in my code.

I got all rows data from excel.

How can I get only one row from multiple rows?

I have tried to read data by using cell number, but it is hard coding and I don't want to write hard-coded program.

```
public Object[][] realExcel(String file , String sheetName, int columnSize) throws IOException {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    XSSFWorkbook excel = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    XSSFSheet sheet = excel.getSheet(sheetName);
    int rowSize = sheet.getLastRowNum();

    String xslData1;
    double xslNumericData;
    XSSFCell checkData;

    Object[][] data = new Object[rowSize][columnSize];

    for (int i = 1; i <= rowSize; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j <= columnSize; j++) {
            checkData = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);

            if (checkData != null) {
                CellType type = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum();

                if (type == CellType.STRING) {
                    xslData1 = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                    data[i - 1][j] = xslData1;
                } else if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    xslNumericData = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
                    data[i - 1][j] = xslNumericData;
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code to give you the correct answer

Comment: By using this code I can read all data from Excel. But I want to call only first row, if first row is not getting match with my requirements then and then read second row data...

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to return only 1 specific row then you have to pass the row number  as a parameter to the function and also stop using the first loop and your `object[][]` array will be of size `object[1][columnSize]`.

please check this code.

```
public Object[][] realExcel(String file , String sheetName, int columnSize, int rowNumber) throws IOException {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XSSFWorkbook excel = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        XSSFSheet sheet = excel.getSheet(sheetName);

        int rowSize = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        String xslData1;

        double xslNumericData;


        XSSFCell checkData;


    if(rowNumber <= rowSize){
            Object[][] data = new Object[1][columnSize];


            for (int j = 0; j <= columnSize; j++) {

                checkData = sheet.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(j);

                if (checkData != null) {

                    CellType type = sheet.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum();

                    if (type == CellType.STRING) {

                    xslData1 = sheet.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();

                        data[0][j] = xslData1;



                    } else if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {


                        xslNumericData = sheet.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();

                        data[0][j] = xslNumericData;


                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }
    }else {

        // report that the selected row number is out of the range
    }

    return data;

    }
```

This function will return a `object[][]` with specific row number, So after getting the required `object[][]`, Apply your validations if it meets your needs or no, Then if no select the other row.